# Sorting and Plotting Output of Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook

Bit of a more tedious question here but hoping someone can help. I'm trying to graph an aggregate value (group by day of week) but display the day abbreviation and order by the day of week number (i.e. display Mon, order it first with index 0).

```
def Format_plot(plot):
plot.spines["top"].set_visible(False)    
plot.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
plot.yaxis.set_ticks_position("left")
plot.xaxis.set_ticks_position("bottom")   

#For purposes of mapping
days = {0:'Mon',1:'Tues',2:'Weds',3:'Thurs',4:'Fri',5:'Sat',6:'Sun'}  
ds['signup_weekday'] = ds['signup_dayofweek'].apply(lambda x: days[x])
ds = ds.sort_values(by = 'signup_date')
first_ride_rate = {
    'success': lambda x: 1.0*sum(x)/len(x)
    }

def GraphMe(item):
    de = ds[pd.notnull(ds[item])]
    if item == 'signup_weekday':
        sorter = 'signup_dayofweek'
    else:
        sorter = item
    de = de.sort_values(by = sorter)

    total_avg = 1.0*sum(de['success'])/len(de['success'])

    plot = de.groupby(item).agg(first_ride_rate).plot(kind = 'bar',legend=None, title = "Share of signups to complete a first trip")

    Format_plot(plot)
    plot.axhline(y=total_avg, color = 'orange')
    plot.set_xlabel(item)
    plot.set_ylabel('Share of Signups to Complete')
    print sorter

for item in ['signup_dayofweek','signup_weekday']:
    GraphMe(item)
```

[image: Notebook Snapshot]

As you can see it isn't ordering as I'd like to on the day of week index, hoping someone has a clever hack. Also if there's an easy way to input jupyter notebook cells into stack overflow would be helpful to know for further questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the graph called *signup_dayofweek*  is correct, you just want to have a different labeling on the x-axis?!

In that case simply add

```
plot.set_xticklabels([days[i] for i in range(7)])
```

(here would be the documentation of [`.set_xticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels))

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Probably pretty obvious but I'm newer to Python in general.

I'm getting an attr error though now: 
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_xlabels'

I'll keep looking into this though shouldn't be too hard

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant _x**tick**labels. Corrected the answer.

Comment: You area beautiful human being and now my graph is nearly as beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: Don't get personal. ;-) But if this answers your question, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).